# Why did Einstein allow unphysical objects in his 1906 paper on $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

In the first part of [this paper](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/214), Einstein considers a "rigid cylinder", "massless cavity", as well as a "massless carrier mechanism" that is used to transport the massless cavity. These hypothetical objects are used to demonstrate, in modern terms, $E=mc^2$, by postulating that the principle of centre of mass holds.

The only problem is, rigid bodies are not allowed in Special Relativity. How could Einstein have missed this? Furthermore, how can we justify the "massless bodies" that Einstein employs?

Comment: Not an answer, but still: physics is very resilient and forgiving, and physicists know this. In most cases, you can use an idealized hypothetical or even paradoxical premise and still come to the right conclusions, as long as the unphysical property wasn't directly involved in the process you are deriving.

Comment: The objects in Einstein's Gedankenexperiments are never subjected to any relevant stresses, so it doesn't really matter that they aren't perfect. Einstein isn't colliding unstoppable forces with immovable walls like high school students like to do. When physicists are talking about "rigid", they always mean "rigid enough to make a valid approximation of the physical system". Einstein obeys that principle. Of course one can do it correctly... but I don't believe it was even Einstein who worked out the equations for relativistic deformable bodies. That level of detail didn't matter to him.